# Data packet transmission probability problem, how do I solve the infinite sum?

Tags: probability, summation

A data packet is transmitted with a success probability of p. The energy consumed is $X^2 + 5$ milliwatts. Find the expected power consumed.

So I used LOTUS to get this sum: $E[X^2+5] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^2 + 5)*(1-p)^{k-1}*p$

This is correct, right? However, I don't know how to solve this infinite sum. I'm not sure how to deal with the $k^2*(1-p)....$

Can you explain if there is a more interesting method that specifically uses probability, or is an algebraic method the only way?

Comment: What is $X$? Number of attempts?

Comment: It looks like $X$ is a r.v., and based on the sum it seems like $X\sim\text{Geom}(p)$.

Comment: @Wolfram Yes, X is the number of transmissions

Comment: @Mark What do you mean? What is an r.v.?

Comment: @Goldname a r.v. is a random variable.  Essentially, your $E[X^2 + 5]$ looks like the expected value of a function of a random variable of a known distribution.  If we rewrite $E[X^2 + 5] = E[X^2 + 5] - E[X]^2 + E[X]^2$, we can further rewrite this as $E[X^2 + 5] = V[X] + E[X]^2 + 5$.  Here, $V[X]$ and $E[X]$ are the variance and mean of $X$, and as we know $X$'s distribution we can just look these up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $X\sim\text{Geom}(p)$ is a [Geometric Random Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution), so $P(X = k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}$.
So, we can write the following:
\begin{align*}
E[X^2 + 5] = E[X^2] + E[5]
\end{align*}
Now, we have that:
$$V[X] = E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$
where $V$ is the variance.
So, we can rewrite this as:
$$E[X^2 + 5] = V[X]+E[X]^2 + E[5]$$
We have that $V[X] = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$ for a geometric random variable, and $E[X]^2 = (\frac{1}{p})^2$ for a geometric random variable, so:
$$E[X^2 + 5] = \frac{1-p}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^2} + 5 = \frac{2-p}{p^2} + 5$$

Comment: Isn't the expected value E[x] = (1-p)/p?

Comment: @Goldname unfortunately there are two different notations for Geometric random variables, one where the $P(X = k) = (1-p)^k p$ for $k\in\{0,1,\dots\}$, and one where $P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$ for $k\in\{1,2,\dots\}$. The first one has the expected value you quote, the second one has the one I quote, and your $P(X = k)$ matches the second one.

Comment: I see, but the sum of the two definitions is the same thing, right? I don't understand how they can have different expected values when it is simply notation.

Comment: @Goldname I don't understand your question, but if we call the two definitions $\text{Geom}_1(p)$ and $\text{Geom}_2(p)$, then we have that $X\sim \text{Geom}_2(p)$ here.  This is because if $X\sim\text{Geom}_1(p)$, then $E[X^2 + 5] = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (k^2 + 5)(1-p)^kp$, which isn't the sum you want to evaluate.  To see this, note that the $(k^2 + 5)$ coefficients will be $5,6,9,\dots$, but for $\text{Geom}_2(p)$ (and your sum) they are $6,9,14,\dots$.  The rest of the parts of the sum are equivalent though.

Comment: My question is if you ignore the $(k^2+5)$, then summing from k = 0 is the same as summing from k =1, but they yield different E[x] right?

Comment: Yes, if you write the sum as $E[f(X)] = \sum f(k)p(X = k)$, then the $p(X = k)$ parts are the same, but the $f(k)$'s are slightly different (one is really a $f(k - 1)$).

Answer (score 0):

Generally if we have a sum of the kind $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(k)\alpha^k$ where $|\alpha|<1$ and $P$ is a polynomial, we can take the identity 
$$\frac1{1-\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha^k$$
And differentiate both parts with respect to alpha $\deg P$ times. We will get a bunch of identities with known left part and on the right parts there will be sums of the kind $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P_n(k)\alpha^k$, where $P_n$ are some polynomials of degree $0\le n\le\deg P$. Then we can sum these identities with appropriate coefficients to obtain what we want on the right and some closed form on the left.